# interaction unit testing using Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have a testing class

```
    public class TerminationRequestValidation : ValidatorBase<TerminationRequest>
{
    public TerminationRequestValidation(IIntHR2BLLContext context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    public override ValidationResult ValidateWithoutThrow(TerminationRequest request)
    {
        var result = ValidationResult.Success;

        /* some logic */

        var isHRIAdvanced = Context.Logics.Accessible.HasAccess(request, IntHRSecurityOperationCode.TerminationRequestSetTerminationDateBehindhand);

        if (!isHRIAdvanced && Context.Logics.Termination.IsTerminationDateChanged(request))
        {
            result += CheckTerminationDate(request);                
        }

        return result;
    }

    public virtual ValidationResult CheckTerminationDate(TerminationRequest request)
    {
        var result = ValidationResult.Success;

        /* any validation logic */

        return result;
    }
}
```

I need to check 'CheckTerminationDate' method is performed

```
        [TestMethod]
    public void Validate_TerminationDateChangedbyNotAdvanced_TerminationDateCheck()
    {
        var context = FakeContext.Create();
        // first stub
        var accessibleBllStub = new Mock<IAccessibleBLL>(MockBehavior.Loose);

        accessibleBllStub.Setup(z => z.HasAccess(It.IsAny<TerminationRequest>(), It.IsAny<IntHRSecurityOperationCode>()))

            .Returns<TerminationRequest, IntHRSecurityOperationCode>((x, y) => y != IntHRSecurityOperationCode.TerminationRequestSetTerminationDateBehindhand);

        context.StubBLL(z => z.Accessible, accessibleBllStub.Object);
        // second stub
        var terminationBLLStub = new Mock<ITerminationBLL>(MockBehavior.Loose);

        terminationBLLStub.Setup(z => z.IsTerminationDateChanged(It.IsAny<TerminationRequest>())).Returns(true);

        context.StubBLL(z => z.Termination, terminationBLLStub.Object);
        // mock
        var validator = new Mock<TerminationRequestValidation>(MockBehavior.Loose, context.MainContext);
        // act
        validator.Object.ValidateWithoutThrow(termination);
        //assert
        validator.Verify(z => z.CheckTerminationDate(It.IsAny<TerminationRequest>()));
    }
```

This unit test off course isn't work. On the one hand I need to call real 'ValidateWithoutThrow' method, on the another hand I need to check that stub method 'CheckTerminationDate' is performed.

Guys, help me to find the best solution! May be I need to redesign testing class to make in more testable

Answer (score 2):

> I need to check 'CheckTerminationDate' method is performed

You don't. You need to test that the `request` was validated. Whether that's done inline, or by calling `CheckTerminationDate`, or by calling some other method, that's an implementation detail - and unit tests don't care about that.

So, your tests should look something like this:

```
public void ValidateWithoutThrow_ReturnsSucessfulResult_When_RequestIsValid() 
{
    var validRequest = //...
    var validator = new TerminationRequestValidation(/*...*/); // don't mock this class

    var result = validator.TerminationRequestValidation(validRequest);

    Assert.Equal(ValidationResult.Success, result);
}

public void ValidateWithoutThrow_ReturnsUnsucessfulResult_When_RequestIsInvalid() 
{
    var invalidRequest = //...
    var validator = new TerminationRequestValidation(/*...*/); // don't mock this class

    var result = validator.TerminationRequestValidation(invalidRequest);

    Assert.NotEqual(ValidationResult.Success, result);
}
```

As a general rule of thumb, avoid verifying how the method works internally. You're coupling your tests to implementation details and refactoring/maintaining those details will be a living hell.

Comment: you offer me to change interaction Test on state-based. You right that its state-based test but in this case I have to stub 2 common stubs in each test.

Comment: My colleague advised me to  extract method 'CheckTerminationDate' to another class. What do you think about this solution?

Comment: Sorry, could you please rephrase your first comment? What do you mean?

Comment: If I write test by your way I'll have to have 2 stubs ('accessibleBllStub', 'terminationBLLStub') in each test. I want to avoid this duplication. I tried to use interaction test checking is method performed. Then I'll write tests for 'CheckTerminationDate'.

You are right about avoiding verifying how the method works internally. But I don't want to have 2 stubs in each test for 'CheckTerminationDate'.

Comment: Personally, I think duplicated code in unit tests is perfectly fine. I think having readable, self-contained tests that are decoupled from implementation details trumps having dry and fragile tests. If you're worried about the size of your test setup, I would look into using [AutoFixture](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture).

Comment: I'm really worried about readable, cleanliness of test. I don't want to obscure test with redundant fake objects.